# setText to a TextView(which is outside a ListView) from a ListView item

Tags: android, listview

**CANT ACCESS A TEXTVIEW(WHICH IS OUTSIDE LISTITEM/LISTVIEW) FROM LISTITEM**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLmkm.png)

as you can see in the image i want to change the value of a textview(current value is "Rs.97") from the buttons within listitem.(i.e. "+" and "-" buttons)

here my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDIkN.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of your code, instead, copy & paste & format it.

Comment: make it static and access it in adapter

Comment: bind your textview with its Id in oncreate of your activity and then just set text in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Make an interface like :

```
   public interface ChangeItemInterface {

        public void doChange(String anyValue);

    }
```

**In Adapter,**

> Intialize interface object like :

```
ChangeItemInterface changeItemInterface;
```

> In Adapter Constructor,

```
this.changeItemInterface = context;
```

> In Adapter, From any View Click :

```
AnyView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 this.changeItemInterface.doChange("AnyValue");
                 // It will go to the Your Activity Overided method which is explained below this


            }
        });
```

> In Your Activity implement this interface like :

```
     public class YourActivity extends Activity implements ChangeItemInterface{

        /// You'll get override method of your interface, here your call back will come when from adapter click happen
         @Override
            public void doChange(String anyValue) {

              /// Here you can update any value in your activity !
            }

        }
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem !

Comment: @Bhaumik, if it really helped you, then please upvote my friend ! Thank you.